# Append My shipping address country in my order Id as prefix

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I want to append the shipping address country code as a prefix in my Order Id. For example, my order Id is 20191107 and My shipping country is the United state. So, my order id will be US20191107. 
I am totally new to Magento 2. Can you let me know how can I achieve this feature with a detail explanation?

Thanks

Comment: You can set order prefix and suffix which is also recommended by magento. In order to achieve your task you can write an observer which trigger after place order sales_order_place_after or checkout_onepage_success you can get and set increment id and save order but this also effect your admin order sorting which is by default set using increment id. Thank you

Comment: this will help you: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/change-order-prfix-increment-id-suffix-invoice.html